# Is MongoDB disk based?

Tags: mongodb

Is all the data in MongoDB being stored on a disk in the computer system? If a query is being run, is it straight from the disk? Because it is from disk, it can scale based on the disk size?

Comment: What do you mean? If it were not disk-based but were instead memory-based it wouldn't be persistent (which it obviously is). You need to specify what you mean more specifically.

Comment: Yes, not really, and no. Nailed it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoDB does store all its data on disk so that it can persist it during server restarts. However, it is primarily liking memory. It relies on the Operating System to schedule which bits of its database stay in memory, and which stays on disk. Queries will perform better if the data is in memory of course because it's faster, but MongoDB (or rather the Operating System) will pull into memory data that's stored on disk. So, in order to answer your questions: Yes, MongoDB's data is stored on disk. The queries are run straight from memory, backed by disk if not all the data fits in memory. And it scales based on disk-size, but you will benefit from having more memory greatly.

Comment: Update: In-memory Storage Engine is available from version 3.2.6: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/inmemory/